# RSpec test writing to STDOUT with Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, warnings, stdout

I want to send a warning to users if they give a `::config` method erroneous keys, but also let the method continue with execution. So, that's writing to STDOUT, right?

```
def configure opts={}
  if (@valid_config_keys - opts.keys).any?
    print "WARNING message"
  end
  # rest of method
end
```

I've got a test that doesn't pass:

```
it "should warn the user against bad data" do
  STDOUT.should_receive(:print).with("WARNING message")
  subject
end
```

even though I see the warning message being displayed when I run the tests. I can't figure out how to get access to the right `STDOUT` object here, because the code is definitely working. I also copied the warning message directly from the test into the production code, so I'm sure there aren't any small typos in the message. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Print](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-print)** is a class method of the `Kernel` module. All class methods of the `Kernel` module are included in the `Object` class as instance methods. And all other classes are inhereted from the `Object` class. So you should expect class, from which you are calling `print`, to receive it:

```
YourClassName.should_receive(:print).with("WARNING message")
```

Comment: That works, but only when I call print as `Kernel.print`. If I just call `print`, the output is shown, but the test still fails. Happen to know why that might be?

Comment: try to substitude `Kernel` with the name of the class in which the `configure opts` method is defined